# How to match n number of lines with regex

Tags: java, regex

I have some text like this

```
Notes:
He jumped the sea-horse
but it looked ropey
Then he left
```

but sometimes its like this

```
Notes:




Clay is only green
When it is seen
```

I need to capture 4 lines of text after "Notes" only so the output should be

```
Notes:
He jumped the sea-horse
but it looked ropey
Then he left
```

and for the second example

```
Notes:
```

I have tried matching the newlines but it only matches after the rest of the regex

```
Notes:.*\n{4}
```

How can I create a regex that allows me to repeat the match for the whole line and a newline four times? (is this a non-capturing group??)

Comment: Why regex?? Java has other options

Comment: Instead of reading the entire file into a string and matching newlines, just read one line at a time.  When you see "Notes:", just read the appropriate number of additional lines.

Comment: I guess the question is why not regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close - in `Notes:.*\n{4}` the `{4}` is binding only to the newline, so it'll only capture "Notes:" followed by anything, followed by 4 blank lines.

You're looking for something like `Notes:\n((?:.*\n){1,4})`

Comment: So given I want to use a capture group to get .*\n are the brackets acting as a capture group to give me all four lines?

Comment: Ah, you're right, the capturing behavior wasn't what you were looking for. Updated response to have an outer capture group, and up to 4 inner non-capturing groups.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, and you want to capture the first 4 lines, not caring if they are blank or not, it may be better to not use regex at all and just split the text on the newline so you get an array of strings. Something like this:

```
string[] lines = text.split("\\r")
```

Then simply cherry pick the first four elements of the array.