# Regular expression for multiple lines in a web service response

Tags: regex

I would like to capture a part of the response I am receiving as part of webservice call using regex. Here is the response I am receiving and I am interested to capture the status of just `ContactMessageTransport` queue.

Status of the queue is being sent in the line:

```
<pogo:Status>Started</pogo:Status>
```

and queue name in the line:

```
<pogo:Name>ContactMessageTransport</pogo:Name>
```

I used `<pogo:Name>ContactMessageTransport[\w\W]*Started<\/pogo:Status>` and its getting the status of other queue as well which I am not interested. I am finding it hard to match just the few lines. Can you please help?

---

```
 <getAllMessageQueueInfoResponse xmlns="http:abcd.com/MessageQueueAnalyticsAPI">
     <return>
        <Entry xmlns:pogo="http://example.com/com/integration/services/messagequeueanalyticsservice">
           <pogo:AckCount>0</pogo:AckCount>
           <pogo:DestinationID>0</pogo:DestinationID>
           <pogo:ErrorCount>25</pogo:ErrorCount>
           <pogo:ID>67</pogo:ID>
           <pogo:Latest>2017-11-28T00:00:00-05:00</pogo:Latest>
           <pogo:Name>ContactMessageTransport</pogo:Name>
           <pogo:NotAckCount>0</pogo:NotAckCount>
           <pogo:Oldest>2017-11-28T00:00:00-05:00</pogo:Oldest>
           <pogo:RetryableErrorCount>31</pogo:RetryableErrorCount>
           <pogo:SkippedCount>0</pogo:SkippedCount>
           <pogo:Status>Started</pogo:Status>
           <pogo:UnsentCount>212</pogo:UnsentCount>
        </Entry>
        <Entry xmlns:pogo="http://example.com/com/integration/services/messagequeueanalyticsservice">
           <pogo:AckCount>0</pogo:AckCount>
           <pogo:DestinationID>0</pogo:DestinationID>
           <pogo:ErrorCount>0</pogo:ErrorCount>
           <pogo:ID>65</pogo:ID>
           <pogo:Latest>2018-03-17T00:00:00-04:00</pogo:Latest>
           <pogo:Name>Email</pogo:Name>
           <pogo:NotAckCount>0</pogo:NotAckCount>
           <pogo:Oldest>2018-03-17T00:00:00-04:00</pogo:Oldest>
           <pogo:RetryableErrorCount>4</pogo:RetryableErrorCount>
           <pogo:SkippedCount>0</pogo:SkippedCount>
           <pogo:Status>Started</pogo:Status>
           <pogo:UnsentCount>0</pogo:UnsentCount>
        </Entry>
```

---

Comment: You'll be better off using an XML parser then trying to regex this.  That being said if you must use a regex, what other language are you using here, python?

Comment: Regex is my only option. Its java

Comment: I can help with the regex and could get a simple example in python going manipulating the text, but I don't know Java well enough.  If that is helpful let me know and I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Thank you sniperd. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you are missing a simple `?` lazy token? It can be used on a quantifier to only match the shortest possible sequence.

[`ContactMessageTransport[\w\W]*?Started<\/pogo:Status>`](https://regex101.com/r/1z1aCq/1)

EDIT: Assuming there is always 8 lines to match:

[`ContactMessageTransport([^\r\n]*[\r\n]){8}`](https://regex101.com/r/1z1aCq/2)

EDIT 2:

[`ContactMessageTransport[\s\S]*?Started(?:[^\r\n]*[\r\n]){3}`](https://regex101.com/r/1z1aCq/3)

- `[\s\S]*?` matches any character, up to `Started`.
- `(?:[^\r\n]*[\r\n]){3}` matches 3 lines after `Started`. The added `?:` is only used to prevent the parentheses from creating a group, which isn't needed. (It's called a "Non-capturing group")

Comment: Nice. That seems to have did the trick. I would like to enhance this a bit more. If I have to limit the regex to check the next two lines after the word Started? I am trying to see if I can match from the name that contains the queue line and till </Entry>. This way I get to validate the response for one queue completely.

Comment: Just replace the `<\/pogo:Status>` part with `<\/Entry>`

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. Sorry for not being clear. I would like to achieve the same result using an alternative way using multiline check like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37687883/how-to-match-n-number-of-lines-with-regex using { and } characters.

Comment: See my edit if it works.

Comment: Thanks again. This works as expected. For my understanding I am asking this question. \r matches the carriage return character and \n matches the linefeed or newline character, is ^ that is used for multi-line matching? I assume the number 8 is indicating the lines the regex to consider. Any tips from you would help my understanding. Thank you again.

Comment: The `^` inside the brackets means it matches any character but the ones specified. So `[^\r\n]*` matches all characters until the line break, matched with `[\r\n]`. Because line breaks differ depending on the OS, this is a safe way to detect them. And yes the 8 is for 8 lines (8 line breaks actually). Don't forget to upvote!

Comment: Hello Nicolas, I have an additional requirement. I would also like to consider the word "Started" as part of my regex and consider only the 8 lines just like the expression ContactMessageTransport([^\r\n]*[\r\n]){8}. I just need to add the word Started here. Can you help here?

Comment: See the second edit.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much Nicolas. The solution and comments were very helpful

Comment: @neomoto Don't forget to upvote!